# How to redirect the requested pages to the page under locale folder name like en\default.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, localization

I am building a ASP.NET web application, the requirements are as following

1. when the user first lands on the website - dafult.aspx page , it should recognise the culture setting, if it is english it should retireve en\default.aspx
2. once the user lands on en\dafault.aspx page, the page has dropdown list to choose language, if the user chooses UK - English , it should redirect them to gb\default.aspx

my web site file structure is as follows

```
default.aspx
en/
  default.aspx
gb/
  default.aspx
fr/
  default.aspx
es/
  default.aspx
it/
  default.aspx
nl/
  default.aspx
```

Can you advise me how to achieve this with code samples?

I am pretty successful building localized website based on resource files, but we have specific requirement to build website in the above mentioned format.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [global.asax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2027ewzw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) hook. You would also need a flag for the current language selected by user. This could be the [current culture's locale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) selected by the user or a flag stored on a [cookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.ASPX), or something else...

For example, you could use a hook function there, for example `Application_BeginRequest` where you could decide where to redirect the current request. If your current locale is `it` then you could parse the requested URL and redirect to the specific folder.

Just to be clear, I would not suggest following this approach overall. I would strongly suggest following the [suggested by microsoft localization process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX). The approach I describe above is not very clean and I believe it is not as fast as the embedded solution proposed by microsoft.

Hope I helped!